# How to Encrypt-Decrypt .pdf, .docx files in php?

Tags: php, pdf, encryption, docx, doc

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt files in PHP. So far I am successful with .txt files but when it comes to .pdf and .doc or .docx my code fails, i.e. it gives absurd results. Can anyone suggest modification/alternative in my code? Thanks in advance!

Here's the encryption function

```
function encryptData($value)
{
   $key = "Mary has one cat";
   $text = $value;
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return $crypttext;
}
```

Here's the decryption function

```
function decryptData($value)
{
   $key = "Mary has one cat";
   $crypttext = $value;
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
   $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
   return trim($decrypttext);
}
```

Comment: You're using ECB mode which doesn't use the IV that you provide. You can remove those IV lines if you really want to use ECB mode. ECB is not semantically secure. It is always better to use one of the other modes like CBC where an IV is necessary.

Comment: @ArtjomB You didn't understood my question I guess. I am not concerned about security issues right now. Though they are important but my aim is to encrypt pdf files. Finally I found the solution to encrypt PDF files, I am using Zend framwork. Furthur tutorial for encrypting pdf files using Zend frame work is available on [link](http://www.codediesel.com/php/encrypting-uploaded-files-in-php/) Thank you for your support.

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question, because I don't see anything wrong with the code (it should work for any data regardless of format that does not begin or end with 0x00 bytes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [this blog](https://bhoover.com/using-php-openssl_encrypt-openssl_decrypt-encrypt-decrypt-data/#comment-1312) to help me encrypt/decrypt pdf files on my local machine using `openssl_encrypt` because `mcrypt` is deprecated in php7.

First, you get the file contents of the pdf:

```
$msg = file_get_contents('example.pdf');
```

Then I called the encryption function written in the blog post:

```
$msg_encrypted = my_encrypt($msg, $key);
```

Then I open the file I want to write to and write the new encrypted msg:

```
$file = fopen('example.pdf', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $msg_encrypted);
fclose($file);
```

For reference, in case that blog goes down, here are the encryption and decryption functions from the blog:

```
$key = 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuiniQBqE70nAuhU=';

function my_encrypt($data, $key) {
    // Remove the base64 encoding from our key
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    // Generate an initialization vector
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    // Encrypt the data using AES 256 encryption in CBC mode using our encryption key and initialization vector.
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
    // The $iv is just as important as the key for decrypting, so save it with our encrypted data using a unique separator (::)
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}



function my_decrypt($data, $key) {
    // Remove the base64 encoding from our key
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    // To decrypt, split the encrypted data from our IV - our unique separator used was "::"
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
}
```